# Dompdf. No se puede mostrar imagen

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, dompdf

No he logrado mostrar la imagen firma_digital.jpg.
He cargado la ultima version de Dompdf.
Pero no he podido subir o mostrar la imagen.

```js
<?php

require 'Dompdf/vendor/autoload.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
$options = new Options();
$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

ob_start();

$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml("<h1>Una imagen 3</h1><br>
<img src='images/firma_digital.jpg'/>");
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$filename = "reporte".'.pdf';
file_put_contents($filename, $pdf);
$dompdf->stream($filename);
?>
```

Comment: Proba poner el path absoluto, por ejemplo: `/home/proyecto/public_html/images/firma_digital.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

Solo tenia que convertir a base64 y solucionado. Acá el ejemplo en un mismo archivo

```
<?php 
    ob_start(); 
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<?php
$path = 'images/firma_digital.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
<p><img src="<?php echo $base64?>" width="100" height="100"/></p>
</html>

introducir el código aquí

<?php
require_once("dompdf/vendor/autoload.php");
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$filename = "reporte".'.pdf';
file_put_contents($filename, $pdf);
ob_end_clean(); //limpiar para cargar mas imagenes
$dompdf->stream($filename);
?>
```